# Is there an "easy" way to get mod_wsgi to reflect Django updates?

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I'm reading http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode but it seems like way too much work, I've been restarting my apache2 server gracefully whenever I make tweaks to Django code as it inconsistently picks up the right files and probably tries to rely on cached .pycs.

Answer (score 0):

I setup Django using mod_wsgi using the steps outlined at [this blog post](http://m.andric.us/post/43754517/django-python-mod-wsgi-with-cpanel-whm).

It automatically reflects updates (although every now and then, there will be a delay for a few minutes - never figure out why nor is it that much of an inconvenience).

Answer (score 0):

If you are having to restart your Apache server then you can't be using mod_wsgi daemon mode. Use daemon mode and then simply touching the WSGI script file when an atomic set of changes have been completed isn't that hard and certainly safer than a system which restarts arbitrarily when it detects any single change. If you do want automatic restart based on code changes, then that is described in that document as well. For a Django slant on it, read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/02/source-code-reloading-with-modwsgi-on.html

What is it about what is documented there which is 'way too much work'?